# How to set scrollTop() of multiple dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrolltop

Thanks in advance for your help!

I am working on a Dashboard that has multiple Bootstrap panels within it. Each panel has a set height but can contain overflowing content, with overflow: scroll.

I have successfully set the scrollTop() on single divs by ID, but I am trying to figure out how to make it more dynamic and scalable so that each panel's scrollbar is set to the bottom.

I started with this:

```
$("#mydiv").scrollTop($("#mydiv")[0].scrollHeight);
```

but I am looking for something like this:

```
$(".panel-inner").scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
```

or maybe

```
$(".panel-inner").scrollTop($(this).height().scrollHeight);
```

Could anyone help with getting dynamically set scrollbar heights?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `$(".panel-inner").scrollTop(this[0].scrollHeight);`

Comment: Just tried that. But, no dice. Thank you.

Comment: @Kousha What is `this[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".panel-inner").each(function(){
    this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;
});
```